# Problem with installing any package in Pycharm Community Edition 2019.3.3 64 bit

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I am fairly new to the programming world so I downloaded the latest version of python (3.8.1) and and Pycharm as my IDE.

Recently I wanted to add some packages (for example numpy) but found out im not able to. For some reason it wont recognize my pip (in the cmd) but for some weird reason Pycharm shows that there is a version of it (19.0.3).

That doesnt makes sence since in the cmd I cant find a version of it and even when I try to upgrade it from pycharm it still shows a warning that I might have the wrong version of it (I know the latest is 20.0.2). Thus I am unable to install any python package whatsoever (from cmd or pycharm).

I have tried reseting my python installation and my pycharm's configuration but I havent made any progress. Are there any posible solutions for an amateur like me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add `pip` location to `PATH` or it won't be available in the command line.

Comment: And how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Brother that is great progress. I had issues like yours too, first learn how to set up a virtual environment for your project. You can install any package there for your project which will not interfere with other projects. Next set your pycharm's base interpreter to that environments bin/python. Hopefully it will resolve your issues.